# I have two tables in SQL Server database - users and vacation

Tags: sql-server

I want to select all users from the users' table and their data from the vacation table as start vacation date and end date  to get their vacation balance and if the user has no vacation taken return 0

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.USERINFO.USERID,
    dbo.USERINFO.NAME AS إسم_الموظف,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(d, dbo.vacation.STARTSDAY, dbo.vacation.ENDSDAY) + 1) AS عددالايام,
    dbo.userinfo.balance - (SUM(DATEDIFF(d, dbo.vacation.STARTSDAY, dbo.vacation.ENDSDAY) + 1)) AS الرصيد
FROM
    dbo.USERINFO
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Vacation ON dbo.Vacation.UserID = dbo.USERINFO.USERID
WHERE 
    dbo.USERINFO.DEFAULTDEPTID <> 7
    AND dbo.vacation.DATEID = 2
    AND year(dbo.vacation.STARTSDAY) = 2020
    AND month(dbo.vacation.STARTSDAY) BETWEEN 1
    AND 12
GROUP BY 
    dbo.USERINFO.userid,
    dbo.USERINFO.NAME,
    dbo.userinfo.balance
```

Comment: Please do consider making *good* use of whtiespace and line breaks, that SQL is somewhat of an unreadable mess, I am afraid. Also, don;t use 3 part naming for columns, it's due to be deprecated. Alias your objects and use those to qualify your columns. [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/)

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem? you are not getting results or what? can you provide some data and expected results, please.

Comment: my query return only users exists in vacation table only , i want all users to be shown while exist in vacation table return there data or not return 0

Comment: I have posted an answer below @Mnhly

Comment: my answer updated with an explanation @Mnhly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the **condition inside the case when statement** while **calculating the sum**

```
SELECT U.USERID,
    U.NAME AS إسم_الموظف,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN V.DATEID = 2
                    AND year(V.STARTSDAY) = 2020
                    THEN DATEDIFF(d, V.STARTSDAY, V.ENDSDAY)
                ELSE 0
                END), 0) AS عددالايام,
    ISNULL(U.balance, 0) - ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN V.DATEID = 2
                    AND year(V.STARTSDAY) = 2020
                    THEN DATEDIFF(d, V.STARTSDAY, V.ENDSDAY)
                ELSE 0
                END), 0) AS الرصيد
FROM dbo.USERINFO AS U
LEFT JOIN dbo.Vacation AS V ON V.UserID = U.USERID
WHERE U.DEFAULTDEPTID <> 7
GROUP BY U.userid,
    U.NAME,
    U.balance
```

Results:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+
| USERID | إسم_الموظف | عددالايام | الرصيد |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+
| 1      | NAME 1     | 8         | 2      |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+
| 2      | NAME 2     | 6         | 4      |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+
| 4      | NAME 4     | 0         | 10     |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------+
```

The script used to generate the dummy data is:

```
CREATE TABLE USERINFO (USERID int, NAME VARCHAR(20), BALANCE INT, DEFAULTDEPTID INT)
INSERT INTO USERINFO VALUES
(1, 'NAME 1', 10, 5),
(2, 'NAME 2', 10, 4),
(3, 'NAME 3', 10, 7),
(4, 'NAME 4', 10, 5)

CREATE TABLE Vacation (UserID INT, STARTSDAY DATETIME, ENDSDAY DATETIME, DATEID INT)
INSERT INTO Vacation VALUES
(1, '2020-01-12', '2020-01-20', 2),
(1, '2020-01-22', '2020-01-24', 3),
(2, '2020-01-27', '2020-01-31', 2),
(2, '2020-03-27', '2020-03-29', 2),
(7, '2020-03-27', '2020-03-29', 2)
```

**Note that** the UserId 3 is retired so it is not included in the result.

**Note that** vacation with DateId 3 not included when calculating the sum

Comment: No worries, you just need to post your question and you will find many (including me) like to help you. :) enjoy coding @Mnhly